# Are Spyder formatting warnings important and, if not, how to disable them?

Tags: python, warnings, whitespace, spyder

I am learning to use Spyder and find my code in the editor is riddled with nit-picky white space warnings:

[image: Editor is riddled with nit-picky white space warnings]

no space after comma, not enough space before a comment, too much space at the end of a line, my comment line is too long, etc.

I have not found any of these to be a problem with Python before (e.g. in Jupyter) and, thus far, ignoring the warnings has not affected how my code is running in Spyder.

Is there any real danger if I ignore these warnings?  If not, how can I turn them off?  They are distracting and would bury useful warnings--should Spyder have any useful warnings.

Spyder 3.2.0, Python 3.5.3, IPython 6.1.0, Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit.

Comment: These warnings are Python PEP8 warnings by the way which promotes [generic conventions about the Python coding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any real danger if I ignore these warnings?

No, they are style warnings so you can safely ignore them.

> how can I turn them off?

Please go to

```
Tools > Preferences > Editor > Code Introspection/Analysis
```

and deactivate the option called

```
Real-time code style analysis
```